# Setters for variable in symfony entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

How I can to do setter for children that doctrine save relation for this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="parents", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="family",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="family_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $parents;

/**
 * User constructor.
 */
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->parents = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

My setter, it dont' throw error and don't save relation:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $children
 */
public function setChildren($children)
{
    $this->children[] = $children;
    $children->setParents($this);
}
```

Users doctrine save, relation not.

Comment: `children` is handled by a `CollectionType` form? if yes, checks its `'by_reference'` option http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

Comment: Also `setChildren()` shouldn't be `addChildren()` instead ?

Comment: Yonel, yes children CollectionType, by_reference add false, and add to user entity addChild, removeChild and all okey ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//Methods to add parents and Children
public function addChild(User $child)
{
    $this->children->add($child);

    $child->addParent($this);

    return $this;
}

public function addParent(User $parent)
{
    $this->parents->add($parent);

    return $this;
}


//Methods to remove parents and children
public function removeChild(User $child)
{
    $this->children->removeElement($child);

    $child->removeParent($this);

    return $this;
}

public function removeParent(User $parent)
{
    $this->parents->removeElement($parent);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This is not a setter, but an adder. Depends on use-case.